# What VNC clients support qemu's audio extension?

Tags: audio, vnc, linux-kvm, qemu

I've read that

> QEMU implements an extension for providing audio over a VNC connection

Unfortunately despite doing a lot of web searches and even installing some different VNC clients and experimenting with them, I have been unable to get this working.

What VNC clients support QEMU's audio extension, and in what versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My own google searches have come up with this list of links :

[gnome vncviewer](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-vnc-list/2011-December/msg00000.html) since late 2012
[Fedora 17 and later](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=840653) since late 2012
[redhat libvirt](http://www.redhat.com/archives/libvir-list/2010-May/msg00912.html) since late 2010
[TurboVNC and maybe TigerVNC](http://www.paulsd.com/2009/VNC/) since late 2009

Most of them seem to require PulseAudio whose performance in QEMU is said to be quite lousy, perhaps because of too-small buffers in QEMU.

As these are mostly bug-reports, there is no guarantee that the patches did make their
way to the actual releases, or that they are still working today.
The only guarantee is that the bug was noticed and was worked upon by the developers.

Comment: With this information I was able to determine that `gvncviewer` has support, in version 0.5.0 and possibly others.